# Get duplicate key names json jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I want an array which will fetch me duplicate keys of the json 
Ex:

```
var catalog=[
        { ip: 'ipId_1', name: '192.160.121.11' },
        { ip: 'ipId_dyn_1_0', name: '192.160.121.12' },
        { ip: 'ipId_dyn_1_1', name: '192.160.121.12' }
    ];
```

Since 192.160.121.12 is repeating, i want an array like [ipId_dyn_1_0, ipId_dyn_1_1],

Tried so far ([Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3wHfB/91/)):

```
var categories =[];
var dup= [];

$.each(catalog, function(index, value) {
    console.log( categories+''+value.name);
    if ($.inArray(value.name, categories) == -1) {
        categories.push(value.name);
    }else{
        dup.push(value.ip);
       console.log(value.ip); 
    }
});

console.log(categories);
console.log(dup);
```

Comment: Not posting as an answer becaouse you've specified jQuery, but I'd suggest you look into underscore.js which is great for stuff like this. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/gYyWd/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var cat_inverted = {}, categories = [];
$.each(catalog, function(index, value) {
    if (cat_inverted[value.name]) {
        cat_inverted[value.name].push(value.ip);
    } else {
        cat_inverted[value.name] = [value.ip];
        categories.push(value.name);
    }
});
var dup = [];
for (var name in cat_inverted) {
    if (cat_inverted[name].length > 1) {
        $.each(cat_inverted[name], function(i, ip) {
            dup.push(ip);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: hey, your code looks not working for some json values 
Please check this http://jsfiddle.net/3wHfB/105/
If the json object :
var catalog=[
        { ip: 'officeGroupName_1', name: 'de2' },
        { ip: 'officeGroupName_3', name: 'de2' }
   ];
it wirks fine, but with a "-". not working. please help

Comment: `de2` and `de2-` are not duplicates of each other.

Comment: sorry for mistake, i regret.

Answer (score 0):

Check:

```
var catalog=[
        { ip: 'ipId_1', name: '192.160.121.11' },
        { ip: 'ipId_dyn_1_0', name: '192.160.121.12' },
        { ip: 'ipId_dyn_1_1', name: '192.160.121.12' }
    ];

var my = {};
var dup = [];

$.each(catalog, function(index, value) {
    if(!!!my[value.name]) {
        my[value.name] = [];
    }
    my[value.name].push(value.ip);    
});

$.each(my, function(index, value) {
    if(value.length > 1) {
        $.each(my[index], function(i, val) {
           dup.push(val);
        });
    }      
});

console.log(dup);
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3wHfB/92/)

Comment: @Barmar, checking for undefinded

Comment: Won't `!my[value.name]` do the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

If you use this:

```
var catalog=[
        { ip: 'ipId_1', name: '192.160.121.11' },
        { ip: 'ipId_dyn_1_0', name: '192.160.121.12' },
        { ip: 'ipId_dyn_1_1', name: '192.160.121.12' }
    ];
var values = {};

$.each(catalog, function(index, data) {
    var name = data.name;
    if(typeof values[name] == 'undefined') values[name] = [];
    values[name].push(data.ip);
});
var dupes = [];
$.each(values,function(name,indexes) {
   if(indexes.length > 1)
   {
       dupes.push(indexes);
   }
});
console.dir(dupes);
```

dupes will now contain an array of arrays (sets of duplicates)

Give it a run and see how it works for ya

Answer (score 0):

I would use lodash.js or underscore.js for this task because of the functional approach. You are more flexible in changing your task when using this approach. 
You can store your data in an variable and later easily transform them to your desired data structure.

```
var catalog=[
        { ip: 'ipId_1', name: '192.160.121.11' },
        { ip: 'ipId_dyn_1_0', name: '192.160.121.12' },
        { ip: 'ipId_dyn_1_1', name: '192.160.121.12' }
    ];
var categoriesObjectsUniqe =[];
var categories =[];

var dupObjects= [];
var dup= [];

categoriesObjectsUniqe = _.unique(catalog, 'name');
categories = _.map(categoriesObjectsUniqe, function(val) { 
            return val.name; })

dupObjects = _.filter(catalog, function(current) { 
    return  arr = _.filter(catalog, function(currentInner) { 
        return currentInner.name === current.name;  }).length > 1;
});
dup = _.map(categoriesObjUniqe, function(val) { 
            return val.ip; })

console.log('uniqe Objects :');
console.log(categoriesObjectsUniqe);

console.log('uniqe IPs :');
console.log(categories);

console.log('duplicate Objects :');
console.log(dupObjects);

console.log('duplicate ips :');
console.log(dup);
```

Here is the fiddle for that.
http://jsfiddle.net/3wHfB/94/